# How to configure CSP-headers with express/node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, content-security-policy

I try to get the  tags working in an express/node.js environment but somehow they always get blocked by the content security policy.

I already tried using multiple node-modules like express-csp-header or csp-header but none of them did the trick. So I went back to 'normal' declaration.

This is at the top of my server.ts script:

```
app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    res.set({
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS",
        "Content-Security-Policy": "default-src *",
        "X-Content-Security-Policy": "default-src *",
        "X-WebKit-CSP": "default-src *"
    })
    next();
});
```

Which gets compiled by webpack, node is running on localhost with port 3000.

It didn't work with just "default-src *" or similar. I even tried to declare every content type on its own, e.g.

```
"default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' localhost:*/*"
```

Here is the script part after the body tag of the html page:
(placing it in the head section didn't change something either)

```
<script src="scripts/loginFunctions.js"></script>
```

Maybe something important:
The HTML output gets served by squirrelly (template engine for express)

```
app.get('/', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.render('login');
})
```

Declaring the header in the head-section with meta tags also didn't work.
The origin folder of the script on which I want to refer gets served by express:

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Strange thing is that this didn't occure on my work environment where everything worked as expected.
Here are my error messages from the browser's (Firefox 66.0.5) console:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/scripts/loginFunctions.js”.
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:3000/scripts/loginFunctions.js ("script-src").
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").
```

And yes I'm aware about the risks but this will be running local all the time and even if it will deploy some day... I just want everything running smooth (or run at all) during development.
Any help on how to fix this will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out on my own. Here is the answer for my specific problem, just in case somebody runs into the same problem:

It seems that the addon NoScript was adding the blocking header entries after they get applied by script or in the `<meta>` tag of the HTML file. Disabling it fixed the issue :)

Comment: Sorry, what exactly did you disable? The tag on the page/server, or the noScript addon on the client(s)?